# Difference between attribute and property

Tags: python, reflection, functools

I'm using lazy initialization in Python in order to save loading time. I've some properties that are initialized only when they are used, so if they are never used, the cost for creating them are never charged. An example of it is this:

```
class myClass(object):
    anotherInfo = 1
    def __init__(self,var):
        self._MY_DATA = None
        self.var = var

    @property
    def my_data(self):
        if getattr(self, '_MY_DATA', None) is None:
            print "Populate my_data"
            my_data = self.var
            self._MY_DATA = my_data
        return self._MY_DATA

    def invalidate_data(self):
        self._MY_DATA = None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = myClass("1")
    print x.my_data
    x.invalidate_data()
    print x.my_data
```

My problem is the following, some events cause all properties to loose state, and I've to reset all of them (to the never used state). I want to do this automatically, so I need a list of all properties.

I could get this through reflection using the inspect mode, but I did not found any way of doing so.

Another is to add the property each time I execute the `@property` wrapper, but how can a write a wrapper that receives the getter function and the object in order to save the properties ?

The other method is to wrap the `@property` wrapper, in order to append to a list in the object(e.g. `__properties__`) what are my properties to reset.

Comment: What assumptions can we make about how the property is reset? Do you always set some attribute to `None` (or at least some property-specific constant)? Or might you have some arbitrary code that needs to run (i.e., there are property-specific reset functions)?

Comment: Yep, I'm going to set it to None. But in a more generic way, I wish to have a list of properties (in contrast to attributes, for the sake of understanding). The second is a plus.